# How to set the default homepage and search engine in the Ubuntu Touch browser app?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, browser

How can I set a default page for Ubuntu-Phone Browser? And how to change the search engine?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As of now you cannot change the default homepage or search engine in the Ubuntu Touch browser app. For the first version, only the core features like browsing, history, tabs were targeted.

However looking at the development trunk of the browser app, I see two branches [[1]](https://code.launchpad.net/~rpadovani/webbrowser-app/settings-page) and [[2]](https://code.launchpad.net/~osomon/webbrowser-app/qt-labs-settings) that look to implement this feature.

If you are missing features or experience a bug, feel free to let the developers know by reporting a bug report at their [launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/webbrowser-app).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for resurrecting your question but it appears (I just installed Ubuntu Touch) adding a search engine is not yet implemented. Touch's web browser search engines are stored as OpenSearch XML description files in /usr/share/webbrowser-app/webbrowser/searchengines - if you add your preferred search engine's OpenSearch description file here, it can be selected as the default search engine for the browser.

You'll need "sudo mount -o remount,rw /" for the read-only filesystem.

It's hacky, but works.